# Create a export to excel button in Power BI

Tags: excel, button, download, powerbi, export-to-excel

I need to create a button (like "Export to Excel") in order to export data from a table in Power BI. This file needs to be downloaded in a folder on my PC, for example the folder "Download" or "Desktop". In other words, this file can't go to SharePoint or OneDrive, but to the Desktop's Memory. How can I do that?

I tried to create a button with Power Automate, but, in PA the only option is to download the CSV file in OneDrive or PowerBI, and that's not what I need. Also, I tried to create an URL from the table, but it didn't work. As I said I need a button to download a excel file (from a table in Power BI) in my PC.

Comment: Why not using the [provided way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data?tabs=powerbi-desktop) to export the data to Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and looked high and low for a solution in the end I found the following steps:

1. Take a copy of the page with the table on which you want to export (This will make more sense further down)
2. On the original page click on the table you want to export
3. Press the Power automate button - as you've selected the table this will automatically select the columns you wish to export
4. Press ... and go to edit - this will open a powerautomate session from within powerbi
5. Click new and create a new instant cloud flow
6. Select Next Steps and pick compose > select PowerBI data
7. Press Next Step again and Select Create CSV table > select Output and ensure automatic is selected in columns
8. Click Next Step and select OneDrive and put in Onedrive account and Location (Screenshot has sharepoint as multiple user will be using this export button)
9. With the file name put the name you want to export and put.CSV at the end.  I included the timestamp option so the files are unique everytime the button is used to ensure files are not overwritten.
10. File content = output from the csv table
11. Save and apply
12. Go back to powerbi and format your button but you will notice the table has gone. Copy and paste the table from the duplicate page you created and delete

One Caveat to note is this method has the same limitation of exporting datasets as pressing ... and export. The downside to this is unlike the standard method this does not warn end users that there full dataset has not exported.

Curbal on youtube has just released a method on how to export 100k rows using the button

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQGGi.png)

Comment: Running into an issue: Followed the steps, everything builds, but the outputs of on Power BI button clicked it is always {} - no data. Checked filters, etc.,